# how to zoom out the map when the InfoWindow is closed in google map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

i want to zoom out the map when the InfoWindow is closed. i tried this one.

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
            infoWindow.open(map);
            map.panTo(this.getPosition());
            map.setZoom(6);
        }

    })(marker, i));

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'closeclick', (function(marker, i){
        return function() {
                 map.panTo(this.getPosition());
                 map.setZoom(2);
        }
    })(marker, i));
```

But its not working. can anyone help me!!
In my map there are some markers and when one marker is clicked, it will zoom in to that location, and i want to apply zoom out when the InfoWindow is closed.

Comment: A marker doesn't have a 'closeclick' event, you need to listen for that event on the infowindow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [google.maps.Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker) doesn't have a 'closeclick' event, you need to listen for that event on the [InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow).

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, 'closeclick', function() {
  map.panTo(this.getPosition());
  map.setZoom(2);
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2xjps798/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: map.getCenter()
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var infoWindowContent = [];
  infoWindowContent[0] = ["test"];
  var i = 0;
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      map.panTo(this.getPosition());
      map.setZoom(6);
    }

  })(marker, i));

  google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, 'closeclick', function() {
    map.panTo(this.getPosition());
    map.setZoom(2);
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```